# partial matching of strings/sequences

Tags: perl

Looking for the string sequences `AATGGGTTCCA`  in multiple sequences. But want to allow for N edit distances (replacements or insertions into the string)

so in a long string it might match AATG**C**GTTCCA (replacement) or AATGGTTCCA (deletion) or AATGGG**T**TTCCA (insertion)

What is the fastest algorithm when dealing with many sequences.

EDIT: because you can match infinite strings.. lets assume 1 nucleotide insertion, deletion or replacement for a maximum of 5 locations
BLAST would also be an option

Comment: Are there any fixed parts to the sequence, or could any base be omitted/repeated? Can there only be single-base repeats, or other insertions as well (as there would be in real life)? Does the number of insertions matter (for example to make sure the triplet raster remains intact)?

Comment: Any base. multiple base repeats. The number of insertions doesn't matter for now, but  a scoring system ( how far off is it from the original) is good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible strategy would be to preprocess the subsequence you are searching for, and then applying the resulting pattern on all sequences.

Preprocessing would produce all patterns that have maximal [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of *N*. The disadvantage is that this requires considerable space: A string of length *s* would produce up to *s<sup>N+1</sup>* possible patterns. To get a regex from the possibilities, you can `$re = join "|", @possibilities`. As the trie optimization will be used here, the resulting regex should be quite fast.

---

#### Example for obtaining the possibilities

Because the sizes can grow very unwieldly very fast, here is an example to obtain all strings that have Levenshtein distance 1 to `AC`. We can obtain all possibilites via

```
my@actg=qw/A C T G/;

sub ld{
    my $distance = shift;
    ($distance and @_) or return [@_];
    my $car = shift;
    my @unchanged   = map [$car, @$_], ld($distance, @_);
    my @inserted    = map { my $ins = $_; map [$ins, $car, @$_], ld($distance-1, @_) } @actg;
    my @substituted = map { my $sub = $_; map [      $sub, @$_], ld($distance-1, @_) } @actg;
    my @deleted     = ld($distance-1, @_);
    return @unchanged, @inserted, @substituted, @deleted;
}
```

As you can see, this code isn't optimized yet. This could be improved via memoization, and factoring out the common `ld($distance-1, @_)` call. It will also produce unneccessary duplicates.

We can then print out all unique possibilities like

```
my %uniq;
$uniq{$_} = undef for map {join "", @$_} ld(1, split//, "AC");
my @possibilities = keys %uniq;
say for sort @possibilities;
```

Output:

```
A
AA
AAC
AC
ACC
AG
AGC
AT
ATC
C
CAC
CC
GAC
GC
TAC
TC
```

---

#### Edit: optimization

I feel guilty for posting such low-performing code as above. Here is an optimized version that prefers strings over arrays, and employs memoization:

```
use constant ACTG => qw/A C T G/;
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

sub ld2 {
    my ($d, $t) = @_;
    ($d and length $t) or return $t;
    state $cache = {};
    my $loc = $t;
    my $result = $cache->{$loc}[$d] //= do {
        my $c = substr $t, 0, 1, '';
        my @unchanged   = map $c . $_, length $t ? ld2($d, $t) : $t;
        my @changed     = map {
            my $s = $_;
            map {; ($s . $c . $_), ($s . $_),  ($_) } length $t ? ld2($d-1, $t) : $t;
        } ACTG;
        [ uniq @unchanged, @changed ];
    };
    return wantarray ? @$result : $result;
}
```

Invoked like `join "|", ld2($N, $string)`. It runs a lot faster and should use far less memory.

Comment: can you explain trie optimization?

Comment: Trie optimization transforms a regex with constant options like `AABXYZ|AABCDEF|AABCXYZ` into a finite-state-automaton, which can run very efficiently. The result would be similar to `AAB(?:XYZ|C(?:DEF|XYZ))`, i.e. backtracking is eliminated.

Comment: and how do you produce all possible patterns

Comment: @Jabda For example, with a bit of recursion. I added a simple implementation above.

Comment: Thank you since what is being searched for is predefined, this would indeed be the fastest way to implement it

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how $result is generated. First one might be slower but its easier to reaad!

Comment: @Jabda If the current combination of input string/distance is present in the `$cache`, that is returned. If the entry is `undef`, then the `do` block is executed. The result of that is assigned to the position in the cache, and assigned to `$result`. Note that `//` is the defined-or operator (available since v5.10). The `length $t ? ld2(...) : $t` test avoids one level of recursion. `substr $t, 0, 1, ''` removes the first character in `$t`, and returns it. `uniq` weeds out duplicates, therefore saving memory, and reducing iterations.

Comment: How do you populate @ possibilities using ld2

Comment: @Jabda the `ld2` already returns a list of unique possibilities. So: `my @possibilities = ld2($distance, $string); say for sort @possibilities`.